# insert consecutive number after .fa header id

Tags: linux, perl

I have a large .fa file that consists of multiple merged fasta files. Each file is separated by header line and begins with ">". 
Here is an example:

```
>DPB1*04:01:01:01 [most similar sequence] for DPB1 in 3507009462
```

I would like to modify each header inside the file by adding a consecutive integer after each id. The id is the first sequence of characters after ">" and before the first space.
The modified header would look like this:

```
>DPB1*04:01:01:011 [most similar sequence] for DPB1 in 3507009462
```

I found some code that replaces the header by a consecutive number but not sure how to insert it after the header id.

```
cat youFile.fa | perl -ane 'if(/\>/){$a++;print ">$a\n"}else{print;}' > youFile_new.fa
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: *"I found some code"*. I'm sorry, but software engineering isn't a matter of cribbing code from one person and taking it to someone else to fix it up for you. If you know some Perl then please at least try. If you don't, and have no intention of learning it, then you should seek out someone who will do it professionally for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ perl -wpe 's/\s/++$i . " "/e if /^>/' input.fa
```

Explanation:

1. Substitute first occurrence of whitespace with counter variable and single space...
2. ...but only if the line starts with `>`
3. Print every line (due to `-p` switch)

Comment: Great! but need to dump it into a new file. I've tried `$ perl -wpe 's/\s/++$i . " "/e if /^>/' input.fas > final.fas` but didn't work. thanks

Comment: it printed the modified file on the command line but when I open input.fas in excel it did not change.

Comment: @user3781528 Correct, the original file will not be modified. The file that you redirected the output to will contain the changes.

Comment: i don't know how to redirect the output correctly. I get an error message with this code. `$ perl -wpe 's/\s/++$i . " "/e if /^>/' input.fas > final.fas`

Comment: syntax error at -e line 1, near "^>"
Search pattern not terminated at -e line 1.

Comment: @user3781528 Seems like it could be a copy-and-paste error, but it's hard to say without more information. Which shell are you using? If nothing else, I guess you could always use the `-i` switch to edit the file in place...

Comment: not sure which shell I'm using. where do I put the switch? `$ perl -i -wpe 's/\s/++$i . " "/e if /^>/' input.fas > final.fas`